# Feedly API Alternative

Tags: rss, content-filtering

We are building a product where we have to display user-relevant content for engagement. I was exploring Feedly API. It works fine but their support team said they'll change $1000 per month for API acces. Not sure where that pricing came from but its very expensive for us.

Can anyone suggest a similar web or self-hosted service which allows following -

1. Discovering sources - finding websites related to particular keyword/topic, with some sort of quality parameters such as number of subscribers, activity rate, etc,
2. Accessing posts of a source in a normalized format, probably with similar quality parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You could try webhose.io:

https://webhose.io/pricing

They have a free tier and the cost is usage based after that, so if your volume is low you'll be paying very little.